# Breeze.js query does not update knockout view

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, knockout.js, breeze

I am querying data via breeze.js which works fine the first time. The second time the view isn't updated.

html

```
<a id="linkQDate">Order by Newest</a>
<a id="linkQScore">Order by Score</a>

<div id="questionWrapper">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: results">
    <li>
       <strong><span data-bind="text: Score"></span></strong>
       <span data-bind="text: Titel"></span>
    </li>
    </ul>
</DIV>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/dbentities');
var isApplied = false;
var dmodel;

$("#linkQDate").click(function () {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Questions").orderBy("Date");
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded);
    function querySucceeded(data) {
        dmodel = data;
        if (!isApplied) {

            ko.applyBindings(dmodel, $("#questionWrapper")[0]);
            isApplied = true;
       }
    }

});
$("#linkQScore").click(function () {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Questions").orderBy("Score");
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded);
    function querySucceeded(data) {
        dmodel = data;
        if (!isApplied) {
            ko.applyBindings(dmodel, $("#questionWrapper")[0]);
            isApplied = true;
        }
    }

});
});
```

Comment: are the properties in 'data' observables?

Comment: i use the breeze.js defaults. I don't know? Maybe  not?

Comment: I'm no KO expert.. Hopefully one will find this.. My 2 thoughts are either, 1) the properties are not observables, so they won't know to update, or 2) because each time you are assigning dmodel = data, you are overwriting the previous binding application. you would need to potentially use the ko.mappings extension to "map" the properties from one to the other. Or something? Sorry for the not much help..

Comment: Also Maybe have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612101/knockout-js-applybindings-after-breeze-js-queries-completed?rq=1)

Comment: Data.results is an observable Array. The link doesn't help

Comment: can we try removing `dmodel = data` and putting it inside the if statement.. then add an else statement with the following `dmodel.results(data.results);` this should update the observable array and not replace the entire object?

Comment: i get an error: function expected

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31878/discussion-between-excommunicated-and-zoidbergi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just using plain JS objects it will not work. Because it does not know when underlying data changes. Use [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for this to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/dbentities');
    var isApplied = false;
    var dmodel;

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        if (!isApplied) {
            dmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            ko.applyBindings(dmodel, $("#questionWrapper")[0]);
            isApplied = true;
        } else {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, dmodel);
        }
    }

    $("#linkQDate").click(function () {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Questions").orderBy("Date");
        manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded);
    });

    $("#linkQScore").click(function () {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Questions").orderBy("Score");
    });
});
```

Comment: so breeze does not return observablearrays? The website says it does. strange. The mapping solution is to slow for me

Comment: Not sure, if it does, you still cannot simply overwrite your model. Make model with Questions property, then each time clear array and push new array values.

Comment: If you are using the default Breeze mapping library, Breeze does return observable arrays for any nonscalar navigation properties of an entity.  For query results Breeze returns a standard javascript array where each element is a ko observable. This is by design. If you need to, it is pretty easy to take the results of a query and put them into an observable array in the promise callback.  We have a number of examples in the Breeze zip available on the Breeze website.

Comment: @jay: is there a better solution as I posted below?

Answer (score 0):

Working code from Tomas without mappings. It is much faster:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/dbentities');
var isApplied = false;

var dmodel = { results: ko.observableArray() };

function queryFailed(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
function querySucceeded(data) {
    if (!isApplied) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            dmodel.results.push(data.results[i]);

        }

        ko.applyBindings(dmodel, $("#questionWrapper")[0]);
        isApplied = true;
    } else {
        dmodel.results.removeAll();

        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            dmodel.results.push(data.results[i]);
        }
    }
}

$("#linkQDate").click(function () {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Questions").orderBy("Date");
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);;
});

$("#linkQScore").click(function () {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Questions").orderBy("Score");
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);;
});
});
```

Comment: Nice to see it working. In this case you can just apply bindings immediately after creating a model and remove checking isApplied. Code will be cleaner.