# Breeze.js query not updating knockout view at all

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze

I'm new to Breeze and struggling with having the results of a breeze query linked to a knockout observable array and then the array not updating the view when populated. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150023/breeze-js-query-does-not-update-knockout-view) questoin, which is a similar problem, but mine won't bind even the first time around. I did try some of the things suggested in that thread, though, with no luck.

I've been working off of the Breeze.js ToDo demo ([here](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/todo-knockout)). Using console.log, my data is coming from my query looking the same as the data from the demo code. The query is pulling a list of breweries from a table that I'm just trying, for now, to bind to a list (eventually a drop-down). Is there just some tiny thing I'm missing here? Thanks, in advance, for any help!

View Model Code:

```
viewModel = (function () {
    var self = this;

    self.breweries = ko.observableArray();

   function getBreweries() {
        dataService().getBreweries().then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            self.breweries(data.results);
        }
        function queryFailed(error) {
           alert(error);
        }
    }

   getBreweries();

});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

dataService Code (in a separate file, but data's coming out of it just fine):

```
dataService = (function () {

    var serviceName = '/breeze/BeerMatch/'; //route to Breeze Web API Controller
    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

    return {
        getBreweries: getBreweries
    };

    function getBreweries() {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Breweries");

        return manager.executeQuery(query);
    }


});
```

and, finally, front-end code to try and bind this list:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/q.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/breeze.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/dataservice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/viewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
    <div class="row" id="Home">
        <ul id="Breweries" data-bind="foreach: breweries">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: BreweryName"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried changing the closing of the view model to "})();" instead of "});" ?

Comment: I just tried it and it did not help. Thank you for the response

Comment: What does data equal in querySucceeded?

Comment: data is what's returned from the query executed in the dataService. This is what it looks like straight from dataService: `[Brewery__Breeze_BeerMatch_Models, Brewery__Breeze_BeerMatch_Models, Brewery__Breeze_BeerMatch_Models]0: Brewery__Breeze_BeerMatch_Models1: Brewery__Breeze_BeerMatch_Models2: Brewery__Breeze_BeerMatch_Modelslength: 3__proto__: Array[0] ` and this is what self.breweries looks like after it gets set: `function d(){if(0<arguments.length)return d.Wa(c,arguments[0])&&(d.X(),c=arguments[0],d.W()),this;a.k.Ob(d);return c}`

Comment: Does 

    self.breweries(data.results());

fix the issue for you?

Comment: It did not. I got a "TypeError: object is not a function" alert

Comment: Okay, when you do self.breweries(data.results), what does self.breweries() equal?

Comment: doing console.log(self.breweries()); outputs the same as console.log(data.results), which is the first chunk of code in my comment above. Doing console.log(self.breweries); [no ()] yields the second chunk of code in that comment.

Comment: What about console.log(self.breweries()[0])? You have everything right with Knockout, you just need to make sure "data" has what you need. You can look at this to confirm that it's just the format of "data" that needs to be figured out - http://jsfiddle.net/79zq4o5v/1/.

Comment: That ends up giving me what looks like a promise object definition that's too long for a comment here. Thanks for putting a quick Fiddle together. It's good to know that at least the code part is (relatively sound). I tried a copy-paste job and not even that is working with a manually added item, so I'm thinking that I'm missing a reference somewhere, maybe? I'm going to keep playing with it and see if I can't stumble across the answer and report back, unless anybody has some other ideas? Thank you all for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why this worked, but I moved all of my script declarations to the bottom of my Index.cshtml file (they were previously declared at the top, but outside of the  tag.

Putting them at the bottom, outside my main container s, in the the same order they were in in the original post fixed the problem and now everything is binding alright. Thanks, all!